# Load xml into webView

Tags: android, webview

WebView doesn't show anything

```
String dataStr = new String(data, "UTF-8");
Log.d("EPAB", dataStr);
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, dataStr, mime, encoding, null);
```

Thera are of dataStr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body class="z">
    <span id="id1"><div class="title1">
    <p class="p">ЧАСТЬ ПЕРВАЯ</p>
    </div></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are trying to load a Web page into webview?

Comment: Where is this html? In asset folder, in any string variable or on any website?

Comment: It's string encoded from byte array. Byte array from file.epub in assets folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

if not work copy dataStr text to "data.html" file and save it on "Assest" then load html page like below

`webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/data.html");`

-- Edit --

To send text to html file

```
    String text = "" ; //text read from file
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/data.html");
            webView .addJavascriptInterface(new webViewInterface(), "Data"); // Data will be used from html
```

At webViewInterface class

```
public class webViewInterface {
    private String text;

    public webViewInterface(String fileText) {
        this.text = fileText;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

At data.html file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body class="z">
    var data = Data.getText()
    <span id="id1"><div class="title1">
    <p class="p">data</p>
    </div></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: without CSS it's working perfectly. Your way does not suit me

Comment: the problem was that the webview cant load css and if you will use css files you need to move it to Assest and use this code webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/data.html");

Comment: but I read this data from file. Maybe you know another way to display epub book?

Comment: you can read the data from file and send this data to html page using JavascriptInterface. let me know if that what you mean i will share full code for that.

Comment: Solved! webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", dataStr, "application/xhtml+xml", "UTF-8", null); It's work perfect